# Question about differential notation ($\partial$ and $d$)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

My question is if, given $f(x)$, it's correct to write:
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$$
instead of
$$\frac{d f(x)}{d x}.$$
Is it incorrect to use $\partial$ in one-variable expressions? Or it just doesn't really matter.

Comment: Is this useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320228/the-notation-for-partial-derivatives?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we have the relation:
$\frac{\mathrm d f(y)}{\mathrm d x} = \frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y} \frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}$.

For your setting, $y=x$, we get $\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d x} = 1$ which shows that both terms are the same: $\frac{\mathrm d f(x)}{\mathrm d x} = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$.

(Depending on the situation, you might want to use $\frac{\mathrm d f(x)}{\mathrm d x}$ or $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ to emphasize what this expression represents.
If you just want the derivative of the function $f$, then $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ is probably more cannonical.)